# Multiple updatepanels on page remove JavaScript Datepicker calender from textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, datepicker

Actually I have Multiple update panels on page, which update different values on server but the problem is that I have textbox to which I attach javascript class for datepicker on Load event.

But There are other updatepanels before that date TextBox, when I update them first calender image with date control which is in updatepanel disappears. or it remove the calender which is next to the textbox.

```
txtDate.Attributes.Add("class", "show-week w16em dateformat-d-sl-m-sl-Y");
```

Before using any updatepanel its like this

[image]

After we upfdate any updatepanel control its like this.

[image]

But the Date controls which are not in any updatepanel are ok and working.

And in  these updatepanels I actually saving values in DataTables and save these DataTables in viewState .... no change in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the datepicker and its textbox both are placed in an updatepanel?

If you do an ajax-postback with UpdatePanels the server will send html back for all UpdatePanels on the page, and refresh all of their contents, so your datepicker will disappear.

If you set `UpdateMode=Conditional` on the UpdatePanels then only the UpdatePanels that caused the postback will update.

Another option is to recreate the datepicker with ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript, but this possibly resets its value (depends on which datepicker it is).

Comment: ok... but what if that updatepanel also postback or update on server next time same JavaScript problem will be there again

Comment: True, then you'll have to recreate the datepicker with javascript each time that panel updates, but how to do that exactly depends on the datepicker you use. I guess you run some code onload, try to also load that code on (ajax-)postback.

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing the INNERHTML of the DIV or TABLE in which the TextBox is present because if you are then its removing the calender control after that DIV or TABLE is being updated.

Comment: no .... in these panels I actually saving values in DataTables and this I save them in viewState .... no change in HTML.

Comment: then you have to rebind the calender control after every ajax request like y34h suggested. To Re-Bind the Calender;  Sys.Application.add_init(function() {

    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarBehavior, {"button":$get("<%=PopupButtonID%>"),"cssClass":"cal_Theme1","format":"MM/dd/yyyy","id":"<%=CalenderEntenderID%>","popupPosition":1}, null, null, $get("<%=TargerControlId%>"));

});

Answer (score 1):

whatever method you are using to attach the datepicker, you must call again after the updatepanel updates

you can do it on server side with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx):

```
// at some point of the method that updates the panel
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this, typeof(object), "someUniqueKey", "theScript();", true);
```

or on client side with this:

```
// <body onload='...'> or in the <head>
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(
    function () { theScript() });
```